# Adding strings and literals (C++)

Tags: c++, string, operator-overloading, user-defined-types

In the book C++ Primer I came across the statement: "When we mix strings and string or character literals, at least one operand to each + operator must be a string type"

I noticed the following were not valid:

```
#include<string>
int main()
{
    using std::string;
    string welcome = "hello " + "world";    //example 1
    string short_welcome = 'h' + 'w';      //example 2

    return 0;
}
```

- Question 1: Why does example 1 generate an error, since both operands
  are string literals?
- Question 2: Why is it that at least one of the operands must be a string?
- Question 3: Why does example 2 also
  generate an error?

I just want to understand what's going on behind the scenes.

Comment: @vlad OK, i understand. removed discussion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may overload operators only for user-defined types as for example the class `std::string`.

So these operators for fundamental types

```
"hello " + "world"

'h' + 'w'
```

can not be overloaded.

In the first expression the string literals are converted to pointers to their first elements. However the binary operator + is not defined for pointers.

In the second expression the character literals are converted to integers and the result is an integer. However the class std::string has no implicit constructor that accepts an integer.

You could write for example

```
string welcome = std::string( "hello " ) + "world";
```

or

```
string welcome = "hello " + std::string( "world" );
```

or

```
string short_welcome( 1, 'h' );
short_welcome += 'w';
```

Comment: Or `auto welcome = "hello "s + "world";` (after `using namespace std::string_literals;`)

Answer (score 3):

In the first case, `"hello"` and `"world"` are *not* std::strings! The way you write them, they are `char`-arrays.

A way to overcome this is by explicitly defining them as string literals:

```
string welcome = "hello "s + "world"s;    //example 1
```

This is part of `std::string`, defined as [`operator""`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%22%22s). But you need to add `using namespace std::string_literals;` to be able to use it.

The rest is explained in other answers.

Answer (score 1):

Literals strings are really arrays of constant characters. As such they decay to pointers to their first elements. Adding two string literals is adding those pointers. The result is a pointer to some totally unrelated location.

For characters, they first get [promoted to `int`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Integral_promotion) then they are added as integers and the result is an `int`.

---

For the first example, when you do `"hello " + "world"` that's actually equivalent to `&(("hello ")["world"])`. This doesn't make any sense, and neither does adding the literal strings.